# Distribution of charges in an electrostatic study

Tags: capacitive, insulation, conductors

I have a question concerning the capacitive coupling between two conductors. The capacitance C between the two is only a function of the diameter of the 2 studied conductors, the insulation thickness of the latter and distance between the two. My question is, since the charge on each conductor is equal to |Q| =|C*V| where V is the potential difference between the two conductors, the charge distribution should remain the same as long as V=1, right?

Comment: ... And capacitance remains the same.

Comment: The capacitance is the same no matter the voltage distribution, it characterizes the coupling between the two conductors. I asked the question because when running a FE simulation, the charge varies with the voltage (even though the difference of potential remains =1)

Comment: Is there a ground anywhere other than infinity?

Comment: only infinity considered as the ground for this case study

Comment: Don't conflate **total charge** with **charge distribution**. They are not the same thing.

Comment: So what you mean is that the total charge stays the same, but not the charge distribution, right?